# Grails ManyToOne Relationship auto-insert to List?

Tags: spring, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have the following Grails classes and relationships:

```
class Book {
   static hasMany = [articles: Article]
}

class Article {
   static belongsTo = [book: Book]
}
```

**Can I do the following to get a correct relationship being set?**

```
def book = // some book instance
def article = new Article()
article.book = book
article.save()
```

**Is the former same as the following?**

```
def book = // some book instance
def article = new Article()
book.addToArticles(article)
book.save()
```

Comment: I do not see a `m:1` instead it shows a `1:m` relationship.

Comment: @dmahapatro so can you please answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes you can.
2. Yes it is.

you can turn on sqllog in DataSource.config and compare result sql.
**belongsTo**  - saves and deletes will cascade from Book to the associated Article.

Comment: when I do delete do I have to do book.removeFromArticles(article) first before I delete the article?

Comment: Yes.  book.removeFromArticles(article); article.delete()